# What dangers do I face in working on this radio?

Tags: safety

[image]

I bought this radio.

I will be putting a microcontroller into the box, and connecting the radio's tuner, speaker, volume control and on/off switch to the microcontroller.

So, I will not be plugging in the mains power again - mains power is no longer needed.

The question is, what danger is there to me in working on this?  How can I work on it safely?

If I remove the power cable, am I then safe to work on it without fear of electrical shock?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only real thing I can think of is if there are any capacitors that get by the mains voltage on the primary side of the transformer. They can hold a charge that can shock you after it's unplugged. But I don't think there are any in a radio.

Comment: If you have to ask...

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DukeDougal Bruce probably means that if you can't figure out the dangers then you probably shouldn't be in there messing around in the first place. That said, you claim you will be not using mains power. So are you going to provide the DC rail voltage some other way? (I'm guessing about 9 V, but the flash glare makes it impossible to read that diagram where it might state the rail voltage.) Can you spend more time describing your plans here?

Comment: It's almost certainly safe, although the flash in your photo perfectly obscures the part of the schematic that might show the output voltage of the transformer. As long as the outputs are a low voltage you should be good. Notice in the schematic there are no caps on the mains side of the transformer.

Comment: @jonk I'm planning to run a normal mains USB power cable into the radio, which I'll plug the microcontroller into.  The mains power will be entirely unused.

Comment: @DukeDougal How will the radio itself be powered? Or is that not the goal, at all? What's the MCU doing in there?

Comment: @jonk no the radio will no longer work at all\, just the microcontroller, which will drivce the speakers, the switch, the volume control and the tuner potentiometer.

Comment: The "tuner" is not a potentiometer. The tuning knob connects to a variable capacitor.

Comment: How will you "drive the volume control", and what is that supposed to achieve if the radio itself isn't powered? If the radio circuit has no power, fiddling with the volume controls (either mechanically or electronically) won't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

> If I remove the power cable, am I then safe to work on it without fear
> of electrical shock?

Yes. There is nothing inside the radio that will generate enough voltage to shock you.

There probably wouldn't be a shock hazard even with the power cable connected and plugged into the mains, since the transformer is double-insulated and there is no power switch on the mains side. The only possibly dodgy bit is the antenna wire that appears to be wound around one of the mains wires (if I am interpreting the schematic correctly).

I suggest removing the transformer with the mains cord intact (disconnecting the blue and two red low voltage secondary wires going to the PCB) in case you ever want to restore the radio to original condition.

In the comments you say that you intend to power it from USB. On the schematic Vcc is shown (above Q10) as 7.5V. It might work on 5V if you are lucky.

Comment: I don't think we can responsibly condone (or even speculate as "safe") working on anything with mains plugged in, no matter the construction/design. It's just too easy to overlook something even in the rare case it really should be safe.

Comment: @TypeIA Hobbyists work on stuff that is powered form the mains all the time, with virtually no chance of being shocked. Provided they use a double-insulated transformer with low voltage output and no exposed mains wiring it's quite safe. I'd be more concerned about using dodgy USB power supplies  http://www.righto.com/2012/03/inside-cheap-phone-charger-and-why-you.html

Comment: @BruceAbbott The transformer is connected to the mains lead somehow. Perhaps through the PCB, perhaps not (see the purple/brown/grey wires at the very bottom right of the PCB; are they connected to the mains cable?). Those connections could be adequately shielded (although plastics that old may crumble), or they may be exposed when the PCB/transformer are removed from the enclosure. You don't know. I would not recommend working on this radio while connected to mains; at least not to someone inexperienced with mains electricity. And I think it's dangerous to claim there's no risk in doing so.